# Ubuntu keeps asking for log in on Odroid although can login as root

Tags: permissions, login, ubuntu-mate

I have Ubuntu Mate on odroid. After updating I modified from `Software & Updates` to keep upgrading from Xenial repository.

After that the login window keeps showing at startup even though I insert the correct password.

I can login as `root` with the same password and from there I tried to remove `.XAuthority` but this did not solve my problem. I tried to modify the owner with `chown odroid:odroid .XAuthority` but again nothing.

How can I login again as `odroid` user?

Comment: Which .XAuthority file (each user can have their own)? Do you have any files in /home/odroid that are owned by root?

Comment: One file in `/home/odroid` is owned by root: `resize.log`

Comment: As a test you can try doing `sudo mv /home/odroid /home/notodroid` then running `sudo mkdir /home/odroid && sudo chown odroid:odroid /home/odroid` then rebooting. If it works then some user configuration file inside the odroid home directory is causing a problem.

Comment: shall I use `sudo` when inside root?

Comment: Thank you so much `mate` (get it? :) ), it worked. Please put it as an answer: I'll gladly upvote and accept it. I really appreciate your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason a file inside of the `/home/odroid` home directory is likely causing problems. You can move the old user home directory and create a new one then migrate your files over:

```
sudo mv /home/odroid /home/notodroid
sudo mkdir /home/odroid
sudo chown odroid:odroid /home/odroid
sudo reboot
```

You can now access your files by going to `/home/notodroid` if you need them, just beware that migrating all those files will likely re-create whatever is causing the `odroid` user to fail it's login process.

**EDIT**
If some files are being copied from `notodroid` to `odroid` might be also necessary to change the owner from `root` to `odroid`. To reset the `odroid` owner the command `sudo chown -R odroid:odroid /your/folder/` should be run.

Comment: I have one more question. I copied one folder from `notodroid` to `odroid` and changed the owner. If I navigate with the terminal is ok but if I try to open the folder form the GUI it logs me off and when I log in again the Terminal and other open program  are not running any more. How is that?